# How to translate SE below coefficient table to latex in gtsummary

Tags: r, latex, gtsummary, gt

In the below example, the html carriage returns stick around when converting to LaTeX. Is there a way in gt/gtsummary to get return characters that are correct in LaTeX?

```r
library(gtsummary)
tbl <-
  lm(time ~ ph.ecog + sex, survival::lung) %>%
  tbl_regression(label = list(ph.ecog = "ECOG Score", sex = "Sex"))

add_significance_stars_ex3 <-
  tbl %>%
  add_significance_stars(
    hide_se = TRUE,
    pattern = "{estimate}{stars}<br>({std.error})"
  ) %>%
  modify_header(estimate ~ "**Beta (SE)**") %>%
  modify_footnote(estimate ~ "SE = Standard Error", abbreviation = TRUE) %>%
  as_gt() %>%
  gt::tab_style(
    style = "vertical-align:top",
    locations = gt::cells_body(columns = label)
  )
add_significance_stars_ex3 %>% 
  gt::as_latex() %>% 
  cat()
#> \captionsetup[table]{labelformat=empty,skip=1pt}
#> \setlength{\LTpost}{0mm}
#> \begin{longtable}{lc}
#> \toprule
#> \textbf{Characteristic} & \textbf{Beta (SE)}\textsuperscript{1,2} \\ 
#> \midrule
#> ECOG Score & -58**<br>(19.1) \\ 
#> Sex & 52<br>(27.9) \\ 
#> \bottomrule
#> \end{longtable}
#> \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
#> \textsuperscript{1}*p\textless{}0.05; **p\textless{}0.01; ***p\textless{}0.001\\
#> \textsuperscript{2}SE = Standard Error\\
#> \end{minipage}
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
#>  os       Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu
#>  ui       X11
#>  language en_NZ:en
#>  collate  en_NZ.UTF-8
#>  ctype    en_NZ.UTF-8
#>  tz       Pacific/Auckland
#>  date     2022-08-15
#>  pandoc   2.18 @ /usr/lib/rstudio/bin/quarto/bin/tools/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package       * version date (UTC) lib source
#>  assertthat      0.2.1   2019-03-21 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  backports       1.4.1   2021-12-13 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  broom           1.0.0   2022-07-01 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  broom.helpers   1.8.0   2022-07-05 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  checkmate       2.1.0   2022-04-21 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  cli             3.3.0   2022-04-25 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  colorspace      2.0-3   2022-02-21 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  commonmark      1.8.0   2022-03-09 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  crayon          1.5.1   2022-03-26 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  DBI             1.1.3   2022-06-18 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  digest          0.6.29  2021-12-01 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  dplyr           1.0.9   2022-04-28 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  ellipsis        0.3.2   2021-04-29 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  evaluate        0.16    2022-08-09 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  fansi           1.0.3   2022-03-24 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  fastmap         1.1.0   2021-01-25 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  forcats         0.5.1   2021-01-27 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  fs              1.5.2   2021-12-08 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  generics        0.1.3   2022-07-05 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  ggplot2         3.3.6   2022-05-03 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  glue            1.6.2   2022-02-24 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  gt              0.6.0   2022-05-24 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  gtable          0.3.0   2019-03-25 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  gtsummary     * 1.6.1   2022-06-22 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  haven           2.5.0   2022-04-15 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  highr           0.9     2021-04-16 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  hms             1.1.1   2021-09-26 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  htmltools       0.5.3   2022-07-18 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  knitr           1.39    2022-04-26 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  labelled        2.9.1   2022-05-05 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  lattice         0.20-45 2021-09-22 [4] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  lifecycle       1.0.1   2021-09-24 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  magrittr        2.0.3   2022-03-30 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  Matrix          1.4-1   2022-03-23 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  munsell         0.5.0   2018-06-12 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  pillar          1.8.0   2022-07-18 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  pkgconfig       2.0.3   2019-09-22 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  purrr           0.3.4   2020-04-17 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  R.cache         0.16.0  2022-07-21 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  R.methodsS3     1.8.2   2022-06-13 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  R.oo            1.25.0  2022-06-12 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  R.utils         2.12.0  2022-06-28 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  R6              2.5.1   2021-08-19 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  reprex          2.0.1   2021-08-05 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  rlang           1.0.4   2022-07-12 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  rmarkdown       2.14    2022-04-25 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  rstudioapi      0.13    2020-11-12 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  scales          1.2.0   2022-04-13 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  sessioninfo     1.2.2   2021-12-06 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  stringi         1.7.8   2022-07-11 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  stringr         1.4.0   2019-02-10 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  styler          1.7.0   2022-03-13 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  survival        3.4-0   2022-08-09 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  tibble          3.1.8   2022-07-22 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  tidyr           1.2.0   2022-02-01 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  tidyselect      1.1.2   2022-02-21 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  utf8            1.2.2   2021-07-24 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  vctrs           0.4.1   2022-04-13 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  withr           2.5.0   2022-03-03 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  xfun            0.32    2022-08-10 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#>  yaml            2.3.5   2022-02-21 [3] RSPM (R 4.2.0)
#> 
#>  [1] /home/kendonb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2
#>  [2] /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
#>  [3] /usr/lib/R/site-library
#>  [4] /usr/lib/R/library
#> 
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want and what you have? I have no issue with this produces "correct" returns, but that depends on what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified a pattern with an HTML line break hard-coded into the cell: `pattern = "{estimate}{stars}<br>({std.error})"`. Use a latex linebreaker here instead.

However, I recommend to use `as_kable_extra()` because it's bee written to support `\n` as a line breaker.

```r
library(gtsummary)
#> #StandWithUkraine

tbl <-
  lm(time ~ ph.ecog + sex, survival::lung) %>%
  tbl_regression(label = list(ph.ecog = "ECOG Score", sex = "Sex"))

add_significance_stars_ex3 <-
  tbl %>%
  add_significance_stars(
    hide_se = TRUE,
    pattern = "{estimate}{stars}  \n({std.error})"
  ) %>%
  modify_header(estimate ~ "**Beta (SE)**") %>%
  modify_footnote(estimate ~ "SE = Standard Error", abbreviation = TRUE) 

add_significance_stars_ex3 %>%
  as_kable_extra(escape = FALSE, format = 'latex') %>%
  cat()
#> 
#> \begin{tabular}{l|c}
#> \hline
#> \textbf{Characteristic} & \textbf{Beta (SE)}\\
#> \hline
#> ECOG Score & \makecell[c]{-58**\ \ \\(19.1)}\\
#> \hline
#> Sex & \makecell[c]{52\ \ \\(27.9)}\\
#> \hline
#> \multicolumn{2}{l}{\rule{0pt}{1em}\textsuperscript{1} \textit{p<0.05; \textbf{p<0.01; }}p<0.001}\\
#> \multicolumn{2}{l}{\rule{0pt}{1em}\textsuperscript{2} SE = Standard Error}\\
#> \end{tabular}
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>